# ListBox in C# and IndexOf Trying to find second occurence

Tags: c#, listbox, indexof

How can I find the second occurrence of something in a ListBox?  If I use IndexOf it will give me the first occurrence, but I would like to specifically see if there is more than one occurrence.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms? WPF? ASP? ...?? __Always__ tag your question accordingly!

Comment: In winforms you a nested FindString or FindStringExact with a startindex on the outer one!

Comment: To get a count use this: `var count = lb.Items.OfType<string>().ToList().Where(x => x == something).Count();`

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the index of "something" that comes after first occurence of "something".

```
int index = listBox1.FindString("something", listBox1.FindString("something"));
```

FindString("something") will check for strings starting with your "something",
FindStringExact("something") will check for string with exact match as "something"

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: close, but do not add 1 as _The zero-based index of the item before the first item to be searched. Set to negative one (-1) to search from the beginning of the control._

Comment: Oops! Sorry, my bad. You're right. Thanks for correcting :)